# How to stop eclipse to close automaticly when trying to import a package in java (Linux)

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, import, package

As mentioned above, my eclipse is closing whenever I want to import a package.

The Error Logs says 
Unexpected Exception

```
Id=4.6.2.M20161124-1400
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.rse.core
Error
Tue Jan 31 15:14:15 CET 2017
Unexpected Exception

java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-18zs: linux-18zs: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLocalMachineName(RSECorePlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.getDefaultPrivateSystemProfileName(RSEPreferencesManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.initDefaults(RSEPreferencesManager.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEPreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(RSEPreferenceInitializer.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.node(DefaultPreferences.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getDefaultPreferences(PreferenceForwarder.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getInt(PreferenceForwarder.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.initialize(Logger.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLogger(RSECorePlugin.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.<init>(RSEInitJob.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.<clinit>(RSEInitJob.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.waitForInitCompletion(RSECorePlugin.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.ui.RSEUIInitJob.run(RSEUIInitJob.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-18zs: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 25 more
```

I use as JRE System Library "jdk1.8.0_121"

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Add linux-18zs to the hostfile in /etc/hosts

Comment: @Kenyanke ok i am in the file. so how can i add linux-18zs in hosts?

Comment: Add a line for linux-18zs and it's IP address.

Comment: Ok, I have added the ip adress with the submask but it still doesn't work and what does the ip address have to do with this whole thing?

Comment: Have you installed eclipse from your distro package manager? if yes, remove it and try with a zip download from eclipse.org